# Checking whether user subscribed to certain channel in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to check whether a user has subscribed to a certain channel in socket.io?

Let´s say I have a channel called `news`. User subscribed to that channel on client-side. But the site´s data is dynamic, therefore the news-tab of the site might not be open at any time. I do not want to create the content for the news-tab if the news tab is not open on the client-side. I know that the news-tab is not open, when the user has not subscribed to the `news` channel.

Is there a way to check that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `io.sockets.clients('news')` and this will return the socket id's of all clients.  If you know the client `socket.id`, you could also call `io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]` (room name will have '/' leading character)

This is a sample I use for my admin clients to call to get client counts per room:

```
socket.on('countClientsInRoom', function (room, callback) {
    var count = io.sockets.clients(room).length;
    callback(count);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When I come around to test your solution, I will come back to accept your answer.

Comment: But what now in this socket 1.2.0 era?